# How do I create new class objects when clicking a button?

Tags: c#

I'll give you an example of what I want to see, but I can't do it in any way:

```
public class User
{
    private string name;
    private int age;
    private int id;

    public User(string name, int age, int id) 
    { 
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.id = id;
    } 
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string name = tb1.Text;
    int age = Convert.ToInt32(tb2.Text);
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(tb3.Text);
    User ??? = new User(name,age,id);
}
```

??? - what should I put in the name? After all, I need to create a new object each time, respectively, with different names. How to do it?

Comment: You might want to use a `IList<User>` instance and use the `Add()` method to add the created `User` instance to it. But it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: usually, you store them in a collection. a `List<User>` for example.

Comment: You never use your "newUser" there - so this all depends upon how you use it - for example `newUser` is fine if you just save that new user for example.  Why does your `User` class not have any properties (public typically)

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(tb2.Text);` fails if someone enters "13badstuff33" for example

Comment: *create a new object each time* **new** creates a new object everytime it's called and you store this newly created object under the same reference (which overwrites previous reference). Technically speaking then, you have new object every time. But you didn't explaing what you want to do with the reference. The question needs more details then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best create a list (`List<User>`) (or other type of collection) to which you can add new elements:

```cs
private readonly List<User> users = new List<User>();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string name = tb1.Text;
    int age = Convert.ToInt32(tb2.Text);
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(tb3.Text);
    users.Add(new User(name,age,id));
}
```

This list could be defined the class containing `Button_Click()` or somewhere else depending on what needs to be done with the created `User` instances.

**Access of the List elements:**

To then get the third user creaded, use

```
user someUser = users[2];
```

To get the first John in the users list, use

```
user john = users.First(x => x.name != "John");
```

To get all Johns, use

```
List<user> johns = users.Where(x => x.name != "John");
```

Comment: And then how do I get the necessary class element from the list?

Comment: You can index them like `users[2]` to get the user that was created as third, or you can select all users with name John using `List<user> johns = users.Where(x => x.name != "John");`. If There are multiple Johns, you will need some other information to seperate them.

Comment: I'll try it now

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 
```users.Add(new User(name,age,id));```

Comment: I tried to use this code, and I get this error
Code:
```private List<User> users;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string name = tb1.Text;
    int age = Convert.ToInt32(tb2.Text);
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(tb3.Text);
    users.Add(new User(name,age,id));
}```

```System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."```

Comment: ahh, you need to create the list before you can add something to it. I have eddited the answer to contain the creation of the list. You can either create it at the declaration, in the constructor of your class or somwhere else (if you for example have multiple user lists). Marking the list as readonly is recommended in case you never want to scrap the list and start a completely new on.

Comment: ```private readonly List<User> users = new List<User>;```
In the new expression, a list of arguments is required after the type, either "()", []" or "{}".

Comment: Thank you so much, thanks to you everything is working as planned.